# How is it possible to cast between types without having to create an instance of the target class first?

Tags: c#, .net, class, casting

I was wondering about the following:

```
private void RandomEventHandler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// SOME CODE IN EVENTHANDLER HERE
}

Button BtnPushed = (Button)sender;
```

How come it's possible to cast from an object in the eventhandler to for example a Button, but without having to create an object of the class Button first?

For example like this:

```
private void RandomEventHandler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// SOME CODE IN EVENTHANDLER HERE
}

Button BtnPushed = new Button();

BtnPushed = (Button)sender;
```

Normally you would have to create an object of a class, which is a reference type before you can work with it.

Please explain. Thx!

Comment: Who says you can? Did you even try it?

Comment: you right, run time exception

Comment: I've corrected the question. Please read again.
It is the eventhandlers object I am casting from.

Comment: I don't understand your question...Furthermore, in your examples, the sender objects are not even in the eventhandler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be mixing up things. From the examples you gave, I guess you might be confused by event handlers, and the fact that they usually have a method signature along the lines of
`void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)` where sender might be an instance of say a `Button`.

In OOP types can inherit from other types and you can use instances of inherited types as instances of base types, this concept is called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism). For instance, the `Button` class inherits from `Object`, somewhere up the inheritance chain. You could say that an inherited type is a *specialized kind* of its base type:

```
class Person { } // Person is our base type
class John : Person {} // John is a specialized kind of Person
```

Therefor you could say that when creating an instance of John, that this is also an instance of Person:

```
John john = new John();
Person johnAsPerson = john; // Perfectly fine, makes sense even
```

But not the other way around, because not all people are `John`, some might be `Steve` or `Mary`, some might even just be `Person`:

```
Person person = new Person();
John john = person; // Won't work
```

In those cases where we *know* that it's an instance of `John`, we can tell the compiler "don't worry, I know what I'm doing", and explicitly cast the `Person` to a `John`:

```
Foo(new John());

static void Foo(Person person) {
    John john = (John)person; // We expect it to always be a instance of John
    // If not, the runtime will throw an exception, that we're trying to do an invalid cast
}
```

To be clear, it's important to differentiate between the Type of an instance, and the Type of a variable:

```
string a = "123";
//     |    |-> I'm an instance of the Type `string`
//     |-> I'm a variable of type `string`, that points to an instance of type `string`
object o = a;
//     |-> I'm a variable of type `object`, that points to an instance of type `string`
```

The point with event handlers is that they usually provide the sending control instance in the form of its base type `Object`. The instance of the control is still very much a `Button`, but we're just looking at it as an `Object`. Therefor you can cast the `Object` to a `Button`.

Answer (score 2):

This is compile-time legal. You can write code to cast an object to a Button. At runtime, if the object *is not* a Button, this will throw an invalid cast exception. This will happen in either of your code snippets.

What you might instead be thinking about is an event handler

```
protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button saveButton = (Button)sender;
}
```

This is not the same as your snippet. You didn't create `sender`, it was passed to you. It was passed as an object. Via the code, you are asserting that you know that at runtime, `sender` is *really* a Button. You're telling the compiler to allow you to treat it as one, and the compiler is going to let you.

If it turns out you are *wrong*, you will run into the same runtime exception mentioned above.

Put it another way. Say you have this snippet.

```
string foo = "FOO";
object obj = foo; 
string bar = (string)obj;
Button baz = (Button)obj;
```

All of this is compile-time legal. Line 4 will blow up at runtime. You create a string, you create a variable that references the string *as* an object, you create another variable where you cast the object reference to string, and the fourth line, you try to cast to `Button`. Line 2 works because you can treat any class or struct as an object. Line 3 works because the object really *is* a string. Line 4 will obviously not work, `"FOO"` is not a Button.

```
Button button = new Button();
object sender = button;
Button button2 = (Button)sender;
```

Naturally, this works. `sender` is a Button. Now relate it back to the event model. The handler expects to receive an object via the parameter. The invocation of the handler is *actually* sending a Button. As a developer, you know this, so you tell the compiler (via the cast) to treat the object as a Button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your example wouldn't work. I am assuming based on the name sender that this is inside an event handler, which, even though is passing in an object, it is in fact an object of another type, not `Object` as you wrote.

So given that, casting sender to it's actual type works properly because the object was that type to begin with.